# Open a sub TCP/IP connection within a Servlet

Tags: servlets, tcp, tomcat6, jdeveloper

I'm developin a webApp with java Servlet technology where i have to open a TCP/IP connection with another program that listens on a static IP.  Everythin is runnin in a very good shape on my localhost( developin with Jdeveloper 11g and its embedded weblogic application server), however when i deployed the application on a tomcat6 server( free cloud), the connection is opened but it doesn't write to or read from the remote TCP/IP server software.

Could you help me out?!

Comment: i open the connection in a new Thread every time i connect to the remote TCP/ip server, it starts and ends in the dopost method of the servlet every time i need data from the TCP server

Answer (score 0):

In your case there might be a lot of things not going ok in your application. For example the servers between them might not be reachable. Have you tried pinging the server you are attempting connection to from the server your web-app is deployed?

But we cannot be really sure of what the proplem is unless pou provide more info about it